# What is '#' operator in C?

Tags: c, operators, operator-keyword

Is there a '#' operator in C ?

If yes then in the code

```
enum {ALPS, ANDES, HIMALYAS};
```

what would the following return ?

```
 #ALPS
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The C language does not have an `#` operator, but the pre-processor (the program that handles `#include` and `#define`) does. The pre-processor simple makes `#ALPS` into the string `"ALPS"`.

However, this "stringify" operator can only be used in the `#define` pre-processor directive. For example:

```
#define MAKE_STRING_OF_IDENTIFIER(x)  #x
char alps[] = MAKE_STRING_OF_IDENTIFIER(ALPS);
```

The pre-processor will convert the above example into the following:

```
char alps[] = "ALPS";
```

Comment: Your answer could be clearer: `#ALPS` alone will trigger an error "invalid preprocessing directive". However, when used like: `#define TEST(X) #X` then `TEST(ALPS)` will output `"ALPS"` .

Comment: so to say something of sorts `char *s = #ALPS` will make sense ?

Comment: @wormsparty: Thanks, clarified the answer a little.

Comment: @user772678: not really. `#` is only used for special instructions to the preprocessor like `#include`, `#define`, or `#pragma`. It is also used in macros, which will be inside a `#define` statement. You'll never see a `#` used as a non-preprocessor instruction. The only case you could see `char *s = #ALPS` would be if you had a macro like `#define FOO(ALPS) { char* s = #ALPS; printf("%s", s); }`.

Comment: ""stringify" operator can only be used in pre-processor directives" is true but not precise. It can be used only in macro definitions, not in preprocessor directives in general, and only with the name of a macro argument.

Answer (score 5):

There is no `#` operator in C.  The `#` prefix is used to delineate preprocessor instructions.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Answer (score 1):

No. `#` is used for preprocessor directives, such as `#include` and `#define`. It can also be used inside macro definitions to prevent macro expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The sharp symbol in C is the prefix for the preprocessor directives.

It is not an operator ...

Answer (score 0):

"#" isn't an operator in C.
But The preprocessor (which operates before the compiler) provides the ability for
_ the inclusion of header files :
`enter code here`**#include** 
_ macro expansions : `**#define foo(x) bar x**`
_ conditional compilation :

```
**#if DLEVEL > 5
    #define STACK   200
#else
   #define STACK   50
    #endif
#endif**
```

In `enum {ALPS, ANDES, HIMALYAS};`
Nothing would return ALPS. You've just defined a strong integer type `(ALPS = 0, ANDES = 1 and HIMALYAS = 2)`, but it's useles without a name to this enumreation like this :
enum mountain {ALPS, ANDES, HIMALYAS};